# Use realm across all threads

Tags: java, android, realm, kotlin

I have DBManager class for CRUD operations and I want to use it across application, I know that Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created and for that reason I'm unable to use My DBManager class methods inside threads and etc...

what I want is to call updateUploadingFileStatus method declared inside DBManager, from thread which is running inside service.

this is my DBManager class

```
object DbManager {
private val realm: Realm by lazy { Realm.getDefaultInstance() }

fun saveOrRemoveUploadFile(filePath: String, save: Boolean){
    val model = getUploadModelByFilePath(filePath)
    realm.executeTransaction {
        model.markedForUpload = save
        realm.insertOrUpdate(model)
    }
}

fun updateUploadingFileStatus(filePath: String, uploaded: Boolean){
    val model = getUploadModelByFilePath(filePath)
    realm.executeTransaction {
        model.uploadedStatus = uploaded
    }
}

fun getFilesForUpload() : List<UploadModel> {
    return realm
            .where(UploadModel::class.java)
            .equalTo("markedForUpload",true)
            .equalTo("uploadedStatus",false)
            .findAll()
}

fun getUploadModelByFilePath(filePath: String) : UploadModel {
    return realm.where(UploadModel::class.java).equalTo("filePath",filePath).findFirst() ?: UploadModel(filePath)
}

}
```

Calling this method from another thread throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException Realm access from incorrect thread.` How can be solved this problem? what is a good style for doing things like that?

Comment: I know it's not a good idea, but your DbManager should be a Singleton, so you can access the same Realm across each thread you need to

Comment: it is already singelton

Comment: So if it were a global singleton, where would you close the Realm?

Comment: Every method call from DBManager closes realm automatically

Comment: You need to create a Realm instance in each of your methods. By having it in the constructor it will be created first time on whatever thread creates it, but none your methods would work if called from another thread. But be careful that you also close them again if doing that. Otherwise you will leak instances on background threads which is really bad.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function code as follow:

```
 public void updateUploadingFileStatus(final String filePath, final Boolean uploaded) {
        mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                UploadModel model = getUploadModelByFilePath(filePath);
                model.uploadedStatus = uploaded;
            }
        });
    }
```

Time ago I solved this problem by using a new Transaction. I also was using a Singleton class to access the RealmDB, and was calling this function inside a response handler from network. This should work.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no difference between your code and mine, except that your transaction is asyncronous

Comment: Do you implicit use a new Transaction inside the realm.executeTransaction() function? P.s.: you used Java tag, but that's not java.

Comment: Yes because everything is same, it is Kotlin

Comment: That's strange because using a new Transaction force Realm to use a new Realm instance, which is created when the method is called. So you're not accessing the realm from another thread.